# Bad message id generated in python on heroku servers

Tags: python, email, heroku, messageid

I'm using flask-mail, which calls `email.utils.make_msgid()` to create unique ids for emails.  On a heroku flask webapp, messages come through to a GMail account with an updated message-id indicating Google thought the id was broken and updated it.  I have seen delivery problems to hotmail/outlook, and wonder if this could be related.

What about the id makes Google think it's broken?  Should I be generating my own ids and overriding the mail library?

```
Message-ID: <5ae0c0a8.c340620a.d15d.d9aaSMTPIN_ADDED_BROKEN@mx.google.com>
X-Google-Original-Message-ID: <152467882097.8.1913443827376089096@21e56170-89b2-40e3-a2a0-830f26b2fb11.prvt.dyno.rt.heroku.com>
```